# How can sum two nested list in this situation

Tags: python, list, for-loop, sum, nested-lists

Given list a, b

```
a=[[[1.1,-2.1],
    [-0.6,4.2]],
   [[3.9,1.3],
    [-1.3,1.2]]]

b=[[-1.1,4.3],
   [-1.4,2.4]]
```

If I just want to sum the list `[[1.1,-2.1],[-0.6,4.2]]` in the list a (not the whole list a) with the list `[-1.1,4.3]` in list b.

For instance 1.1+(-1.1) then (-2.1)+4.3 and so on. After that store back to an empty list. Can I do this with for loop?
In this case, the final output will be[[0, 2.2],[-1.7, 8.5]]

Comment: Please add the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import numpy as np
c = (np.array(a[0]) + b[0]).tolist()
```

Output:

```
>>> c
[[0.0, 2.1999999999999997], [-1.7000000000000002, 8.5]]
```

**Update** Using for loop:

```
 c = []
 for row in a[0]: 
     c.append([])
     for x, y in zip(row, b[0]):
         c[-1].append(x+y)
```

**Update**: Using list comprehension

```
c = [[x + y for x,y in zip(row, b[0])] for row in a[0]]
```

Output:

```
>>> c
[[0.0, 2.1999999999999997], [-1.7000000000000002, 8.5]]
```

Comment: Is there any other methods other than using numpy. Thank you for helping

Comment: Should I add the one with `for loop`?

Comment: If possible 