# How to sum up two different nested lists?

Tags: python, for-loop, sum, nested-lists

```
list_a = [[[1.1, 2.2],
           [3.3, 4.4]],
          [[5.5, 6.6],
           [7.7, 8.8]]]

list_b = [[1.1, 2.2],
          [3.3, 4.4]]
```

I just want to sum the list `[[1.1, 2.2], [3.3, 4.4]]` in the list_a with the list `[1.1, 2.2]` in list_b

For example: `1.1+1.1, 2.2+1.1` then `3.3+2.2, 4.4+2.2`. After that the output will store back to an empty list. `result = [[2.2, 3.3], [5.5,6.6]]`.

I don't really know how to solve this question with for-loop.

Comment: Either use a for loop with index or use `zip` to go through both lists together. (And on innermost level you need a loop for innermost list from `list_a` while you take only one value from `list_b`)

Comment: Nearly identical to: [How can I sum two nested lists in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66981903/how-can-i-sum-two-nested-lists-in-this-case). Curious that both were today, 8 hrs apart.

Comment: @aneroid One more: [How can sum two nested lists in this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66982447/how-can-sum-two-nested-list-in-this-situation/66982525#66982525). This I answered in the Morn Asked 8 hours ago. Looks like it's a question from some test.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh The one you linked was the one I was looking for actually. I posted a "what to do" comment to to the OP on your answer. Ending up finding the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip to iterate over the two lists at the same time.

```
result = []
for la, lb in zip(list_a, list_b):
    for l, summand in zip(la, lb):
        result.append(list(map(lambda x: x + summand, l)))

print(result)
```

Or, if you want to keep the results separated:

```
result = []
for la, lb in zip(list_a, list_b):
    temp_result = []
    for l, summand in zip(la, lb):
        temp_result.append(list(map(lambda x: x + summand, l)))
    result.append(temp_result)
    
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension with `zip`:

```
result = [[round(b+a, 1) for a in A] for A, b in zip(list_a[0], list_b[0])]
print(result) # [[2.2, 3.3], [5.5, 6.6]]
```

If you don't want to round off the numbers, you can skip that.